# Handler not working while using with roles in ansible

Tags: redhat, ansible

This is my lamp/tasks/main.yaml file  (lamp is the role name)

```
- import_task: httpd.yaml
- import_task: php.yaml
- notify: restart httpd
```

this is my lamp/handlers/main.yaml file

```
 - name: restart httpd
   service:
    name: httpd
    state: restarted
    enabled: yes
```

my main playbook file is:

```
  - hosts: server1
    remote_user: root
    roles:
       - lamp
```

While executing playbook iam getting following error:

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module 
name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/playbooks/lamp/tasks/main.yaml': line 1, 
column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- import_task: httpd.yaml
  ^ here


The error appears to have been in '/playbooks/lamp/tasks/main.yaml': line 1, 
column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- import_task: httpd.yaml
  ^ here

exception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleParserError'>
exception: no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled 
module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/playbooks/lamp/tasks/main.yaml': line 1, 
column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- import_task: httpd.yaml
  ^ here
```

Iam using ansible 7.4 on centos7.Without handler it is working file.But while using handler it is not working.I recently started learing ansible.Pls help me to find a solution.Iam not understanding why handler is not supporting..?

Comment: Do you need the `---` at the top of your `.yaml` files? And should they have the `.yml` extension rather than `.yaml`? Just possible causes for things I've encountered in the past!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in question is because `import_task` is incorrect syntax, use `import_tasks` (plural) instead.

But handlers can be attached to / notified from tasks, and `import_tasks` is not a task itself, so it will not do what you expect. You should notify handler from individual tasks that should trigger service restart (like configuration changes).

Comment: thanks for the replay.Let me try that and i will reach you back.

Comment: i have tried with -import_tasks..but it still giving same error..what to do?Pls help me.

Comment: When i remove -notify for handler...it is working fine.handler is causing issue.

Comment: Well... this is exactly what I told you "You should notify handler from individual tasks".

Comment: thanks for replay dude.....that means i have to use handler in both html.yaml and php.yaml?

Comment: thanks dude ..Now i got the solution for it.I specified notify in wrong place.Thanks for the help..